# Extjs htmleditor placeholder

Tags: javascript, extjs, placeholder

We have this problem,

The htmleditor needs a placeholder but Extjs doesn't have it implemented,
so we are looking some way in order to show some info that disapears when the user starts writting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This extension](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303115-HTMLEditor-Extended-(emptyText-amp-invalidMark-amp-allowBlank-amp-min-max-length-amp-FormValidation)) posted on Sencha forum may help.

Comment: It worked pretty well, but i had to modify it a bit because we were using binds and the field was binded to a grid.